# Sencha vs. jQuery Touch

Tags: jquery, jqtouch, sencha-touch

Which one of these is the better choice? Is there a better choice? Which has better documentation and community?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446186/sencha-touch-vs-jqtouch

Comment: Oh, sorry. Thanks for the link anyhow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the below link -

http://9-bits.com/post/723711597/jqtouch-and-sencha-touch

you can google out for more of them.

Comment: Hey, I know that guy.

Answer (score 2):

Sencha touch is better. JqueryMobile is more easy, but when you can understand sencha touch, u will build more powerful apps than jquerymobile.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build an iOS app then you may go for Phonegap + sencha because sencha makes it looks like a real native app and has explicit iPad support. It will work very well for iPhone. But if you want to port the same app in Android, you need to rethink; it is slower in android due to low hardware specs. It is somewhat better in HTC, S3 and other high end android devices because of their good specs.

If the requirement is to develop a large enterprise application with lots of emphasis on performance, security, extensibility etc, opting for Sencha Touch could be a good decision. But if you are looking for simple web based and very less time to market applications, jQuery Mobile could be a good decision because of its simplicity and its very Web-centric approach to development.

Earlier ST had very less documentation, but now i will say documentation of ST is as good as JQM. [Sencha Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/)

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch is wayy easier and has much more features than JQMobile. It also has a way to store and sort data, lists, filters, charts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sench touch is only developed for webkit browsers. Chrome and safari will work, but the android browser may have issues.

If your final project involves desktop interaction, bear that limitation in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a project with Sencha Touch 2 and found it is awesome. Previously I used Sencha Touch 1.1 and it wasn't good, specially the performance. HOwever, a lot improvement in the Sencha Touch 2.0. Also, the Sencha Architecture is really good, it really helps you to get things done quickly. So, my suggestion is go for Sencha Touch 2 and if it is possible, use Sencha Architect

Answer (score 0):

NB Sencha Touch does not support Android Honeycomb!