# jQuery or jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, android, iphone, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm making a fairly simple mobile version for our website. It's not going to have every website option and the buttons I will be designing myself. For their functionality though, being pop up and sliding and stuff I was considering using jquery, then I noticed jquery Mobile. I don't think I'm going to need all the theming options that jquery mobile has.

Would it be better then to use jquery or jquery mobile for my mobile project?

Comment: jquery mobile overcomes some incompatibility issues between various mobile browsers.

Comment: JQTouch is another js framework for mobile webapps, and its performance is better than jquery mobile. It is recommended to you. http://jqtouch.com/

Comment: @allentranks - that looks interesting as a paired down version of jqm, though the docs could use a lot of work. I see a lot of touting of sass and compass, would I be correct at assuming that jqtouch is currently aimed at ruby development?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I don't know that too much..So far as I know, jqtouch is older than jqmobile. However, jqtouch is now a part of Sencha and has a new name "SenchaTouch". please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446186/sencha-touch-vs-jqtouch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Mobile actually includes all of jQuery. It is not smaller but rather adds in

- Themeing
- Mobile widgets (like buttons, dialogs, lists)
- Markup initializers (so that your widgets can be initialized by adding an attribute to the html)
- An event system for detecting touchscreen events (like swipe)
- A hash-navigation system so that the back button works with it's ajax navigation
- Some other fairly minor stuff (mostly facades to fix browser compatibility issues)

If you do not need any of those things then there is no point including jQuery Mobile. If you want only hash-navigation then you can more easily just get a jQuery plugin targeted at that only. I would not use jQuery Mobile unless you use its theming/widgets and navigation system as it can be a bit of a pain if you stray off the tracks.

Answer (score 2):

How about `Bootstrap`? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Bootstrap v2 introduced a set of new features for creating mobile web applications. It does only have UI elements but it is really easy to work with Bootstrap and it makes web application development very quick! Worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) is built on top of jQuery. It is designed to tackle most compatibility issues among mobile devices, so it's well worth considering.

> A unified, HTML5-based user interface system for all popular mobile
>   device platforms, built on the rock-solid jQuery and jQuery UI
>   foundation. Its lightweight code is built with progressive
>   enhancement, and has a flexible, easily themeable design.

Answer (score 0):

Both! JQueryMobile for UI and JQuery for development stuff.... you just need to take care on footprint...